# Azure AppService fails to pull docker image from Azure Container Registry few times

Tags: azure, docker

Since yesterday I've got an issue with Azure App Service. I'm deploying a new environment using Terraform

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "app" {
    name                    = "awake-kingfish"
    location                = azurerm_resource_group.app_group.location
    resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.app_group.name
    app_service_plan_id     = azurerm_app_service_plan.service_plan.id
    https_only              = true
    client_affinity_enabled = false
    tags                    = local.tags
    app_settings            = {
        "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME"         = var.docker_username
        "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL"              = var.docker_url
        "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD"         = var.docker_password
    }
    site_config {
        always_on           = true
        linux_fx_version    = "DOCKER|${var.docker_image}:${var.tag}"
    }
}
```

The variables `docker_username`, `docker_url`, `docker_password`, `docker_image` and `tag` comes in from CI/CD pipeline and are 100% correct (the same pipeline creates that image and pushes it to Azure Container Registry). When App Service is starting it fails to download image 4 times, but then it pulls it without any issue or any action from my side. Here is docker log from App Service:

```
2020-08-13T15:49:11.472Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: ****.azurecr.io/****:9dd776f05efd0a7ae981446c5e06d45c5c756df9
2020-08-13T15:49:11.682Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://****.azurecr.io/v2/****/manifests/9dd776f05efd0a7ae981446c5e06d45c5c756df9: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}

2020-08-13T15:49:11.685Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2020-08-13T15:49:11.686Z INFO  - Stopping site awake-kingfish because it failed during startup.
2020-08-13T15:49:13.428Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: ****.azurecr.io/****:9dd776f05efd0a7ae981446c5e06d45c5c756df9
2020-08-13T15:49:13.611Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://****.azurecr.io/v2/****/manifests/9dd776f05efd0a7ae981446c5e06d45c5c756df9: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}

2020-08-13T15:49:13.613Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2020-08-13T15:49:13.615Z INFO  - Stopping site awake-kingfish because it failed during startup.
2020-08-13T15:49:17.655Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: ****.azurecr.io/****:9dd776f05efd0a7ae981446c5e06d45c5c756df9
2020-08-13T15:49:17.851Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://****.azurecr.io/v2/****/manifests/9dd776f05efd0a7ae981446c5e06d45c5c756df9: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}

2020-08-13T15:49:17.853Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2020-08-13T15:49:17.854Z INFO  - Stopping site awake-kingfish because it failed during startup.
2020-08-13T15:49:20.549Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: ****.azurecr.io/****:9dd776f05efd0a7ae981446c5e06d45c5c756df9
2020-08-13T15:49:20.736Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://****.azurecr.io/v2/****/manifests/9dd776f05efd0a7ae981446c5e06d45c5c756df9: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}

2020-08-13T15:49:20.745Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2020-08-13T15:49:20.746Z INFO  - Stopping site awake-kingfish because it failed during startup.
2020-08-13T15:54:54.181Z INFO  - Pulling image: ****.azurecr.io/****:9dd776f05efd0a7ae981446c5e06d45c5c756df9
2020-08-13T15:54:55.076Z INFO  - 9dd776f05efd0a7ae981446c5e06d45c5c756df9 Pulling from ****
2020-08-13T15:54:55.084Z INFO  - cbdbe7a5bc2a Pulling fs layer
// ...
2020-08-13T15:55:48.435Z INFO  - 7715080b9d20 Extracting 19MB / 19MB
2020-08-13T15:56:17.866Z INFO  - 7715080b9d20 Pull complete
2020-08-13T15:56:17.970Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:8a2da38f410b91b821ccf2ff2ccdfba12999ea10dc2aa5a60741f3609251cfc5
2020-08-13T15:56:18.067Z INFO  -  Status: Downloaded newer image for ****.azurecr.io/****:9dd776f05efd0a7ae981446c5e06d45c5c756df9
2020-08-13T15:56:18.093Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 1 Minutes and 23 Seconds
2020-08-13T15:56:18.116Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2020-08-13T15:56:18.116Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 1813:80 --name awake-kingfish_0_39ad6980 -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITES_PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=awake-kingfish -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=awake-kingfish.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=c4a671a5f8662a541a877e364dbc007723397b4ed45078d3ae1254f25f96e556 ****.azurecr.io/****:9dd776f05efd0a7ae981446c5e06d45c5c756df9  

2020-08-13T15:56:18.116Z INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2020-08-13T15:56:52.006Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container awake-kingfish_0_39ad6980 for site awake-kingfish
2020-08-13T15:56:53.047Z INFO  - Container awake-kingfish_0_39ad6980 for site awake-kingfish initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
```

This is a huge issue, because it renders E2E tests in pipeline useless since they will always fail. Last month or so it worked fine with this setup.

Comment: if you claim it worked fine before and does not anymore now, then you should address this with Azure Support

Comment: Azure support directed me here, but I guess I'll need to pay that extra 29$.

Comment: If you can prove to them (with logs etc) that this worked fine before, then I would stress with them that this should be covered with the standard support

Comment: Standard support covers only billing/quota issues, any technical stuff require paid support. I can't also post a question o MSN forums, because after submit it throws access denied.